# I need to write error and exception in stdout.log in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have tried to remove **System.out.println("I am Ranjit")** from log file on tomcat. By setting Context attribute in Context.xml **swallowOutput="true"**, It works fine with stdout.log.

But, Start creating log in catalina.log which is not fine.

I want to log only ERROR and EXCEPTION on stdout.log. I have tried it by setting **logging.properties** as below:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ERROR
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

&

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = ERROR
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

But it does not work. Please, help me out.

Comment: *"Plz, help me out."*  Please spell words like 'please' correctly.  This is an international audience, and you are not sending a text message.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know what you are really asking here.  However, if you are trying to change the format of the logger messages produced by java.util.logging, will need to write a custom Formatter class to do this.

It might be a better to switch to log4j logging as described here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

Comment: I do not want to format the logger message. I just want to log only ERROR and EXCEPTION in stdout.jog. Right now, i don't want to use Log4j .

Comment: @RanjitKumar - I don't understand.  What you are describing >>is<< changing the format of the log messages.  You can't leave the other stuff out without changing the format.